# How to use leaflet "openstreetmap" with flutter?

Tags: flutter, leaflet, openstreetmap, osmdroid, leaflet.draw

I need help to integrate leaflet maps in flutter. The project I'm working on requires showing custom markers, animations, routes and drawings on the map. But I can't find any documentation or tutorials explaining this in flutter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `flutter_map` package for that. That's one of two most widely used maps packages (next to `google_maps_flutter`, which is obviously only for Google Maps).

https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map

It features all things that you need AFAIR.

Comment: Dear googler, please notice: The flutter_map repository is licensed under BSD-3 clause!

Answer (score 3):

You may check out the below Flutter Maps widget which allows you to render tiles from different services like OpenStreetMaps, Azure Maps, etc.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_maps

It has the features you have requested like markers, adding animations, drawing routes on the maps, highlight a region, etc. Check the below links for more details.

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/markers

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/vector-layers/polyline-layer#adding-polylines